# Morphisms to $\mathbb{P}^n _R$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

My question refers to a step in the proof of Thm. 16.4.1 (page 424) in Ravi Vakil's script "Foundations of Algebraic Geometry":

[image]

Here the whole pdf:

math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGdec3014public.pdf

Let $\pi:X \to \mathbb{P}^n _R$ a morphism of schemes, where $\mathbb{P}^n _R= Proj(R[x_0, x_1, ... , x_n]$. Obviously every global section $x_i \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n _R}(1))$ can be interpet as morphism $x_i:\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n _R} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n _R}(1)$, therefore $s_i := \pi^*x_i \in \Gamma(X, \pi^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n _R}(1)))$ is well defined.

Let restrict $\pi$ to $D_+(s_i) \to D_+(x_i)= Spec(R[x_0/x_i, x_1/x_i, ... , x_n/x_i]$. Since $D_+(x_i) \subset \mathbb{P}^n _R$ affine, the restricted morphism $\pi \vert_{D_+(s_i)}:D_+(s_i) \to D_+(x_i)$ is completely determined by $(\pi \vert_{D_+(s_i)})^ {\#}: R[x_0/x_i, x_1/x_i, ... , x_n/x_i] \to \Gamma(D_+(s_i), \mathcal{O}_X), x_j/x_i \to (\pi \vert_{D_+(s_i)})^ {\#}(x_j/x_i)$ on the "ring side".

Remark: Here $(\pi \vert_{D_+(s_i)})^ {\#}$ is the ring morphism on global sections of $\pi \vert_{D_+(s_i)}$.

My question is why $(\pi \vert_{D_+(s_i)})^ {\#}(x_j/x_i)= s_j/s_i$?

Answer (score 1):

Think of what happens when $R$ is an algebraically closed field $k$. Then $\mathbb{P}^n$ is a set of equivalence classes $[a_0:\cdots:a_n] = \{(\lambda a_0, \dots,\lambda a_n):\lambda \in k^\times\}$. To give a morphism $\pi : X \to \mathbb{P}^n$ is to give $n + 1$ functions $s_0,\dots,s_n : X \to k$ such that

$$ \pi(x) = [s_0(x) : \dots :s_n(x)] $$

For this to be well-defined, $s_0,\dots,s_n$ should not have a common zero.

The section $x_i$ is the $i$-th coordinate of $\mathbb{P}^n$ and its pullback under $\pi$ is $s_i$, the $i$-th coordinate of $\pi(X)$. To make this all precise, we turn to the affine coordinate rings.

The affine open $D(x_i)$ is

$$ D(x_i) = \operatorname{Spec} k[x_0/x_i, \dots, x_n/x_i] = \{[a_0 : \dots : a_n] \in \mathbb{P}^n : a_i = 1\} $$

We have $\pi^{-1}(D(x_i)) = \{ x \in X : s_i(x) \ne 0 \} = D(s_i)$. The affine morphism we get is

$$ \pi|_{D(s_i)} : x \mapsto \left( \frac{s_0(x)}{s_i(x)}, \dots, \widehat{\frac{s_i(x)}{s_i(x)}} , \dots, \frac{s_n(x)}{s_i(x)} \right). $$

Thus,

$$ (\pi|_{D(s_i)})^\sharp(x_j/x_i) = s_j/s_i. $$

Recall: if you have a morhism of affine varieties $f : X \to \mathbb{A}^n$ given by $f(x) = (f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x))$ then the map of coordinate rings is given by $f^\sharp : k[y_1,\dots,y_n] \to k[X]$, $f^\sharp(y_j) = f_j$.

When $R$ is any ring, not necessarily an algebraically closed field, then you can no longer thing of $\mathbb{P}^n_R$ as a set of equivalence classes in this way. You can however think of $\mathbb{P}^n_R$ as $n + 1$ copies of $\mathbb{A}^n_R$ glued together appropriately.

Given a morphism $\pi : X \to \mathbb{P}^n_R$. The sections $s_i := \pi^* x_i$ generate the invertible sheaf $\mathscr L := \pi^* \mathcal O(1)$. The transition functions for $\mathcal O(1)$ are $x_j/x_i$ and these pullback under $\pi$ to the transition functions $\pi^*(x_j/x_i) = s_j/s_i$ on $\mathscr L$ (c.f. 16.3.7.(3)).

We know what $\pi^*$ does to $x_0,\dots,x_n$. When we localize (homogeneously) at $x_i$, we we have isn't just a module, it's a ring. However, the ring map is still determined by the module map and the module map sends $x_j/x_i$ to $s_j/s_i$. Hence the ring map sends $x_j/x_i$ to $s_j/s_i$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Your last step seems be not clear to me. Indeed, restricting the $x_j$'s to $D_+(x_i)$ we get well defined $x_j/x_i \to \pi^*(x_j/x_i) = s_j/s_i $. But your last step how does it provides $x_j/x_i \to (\pi \vert _{D_+(x_i)})^{\#}(x_j/x_i) = s_j/s_i $ on global sections isn't clear to me.

Comment: So to explain it a bit clumsy: How do you retrieve $\pi$ back from $\pi^*$?

Comment: @KarlPeter I don't know this well enough to give a good explanation I suppose. People who know better than me will say that this follows by definition. This is true but not necessarily helpful. Maybe that this "follows by definition" is why it's hard to explain because to understand this you need to understand the definitions...

Comment: Here's how I think of it: the "coordinate function" $x_j$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$ isn't well defined but $x_j/x_i$ is and it is a transition map and it corresponds to the transition map $s_j/s_i$ through the pullback $\pi^*$. You should think of $\mathcal O(1)$ as fixing the identity embedding of $\mathbb{P}^n$ to itself which in turn fixes an affine cover in which $x_j/x_i$ are transitions. Similarly, $\pi^*\mathcal O(1)$ fixes an embedding $X \to \mathbb{P}^n$, an affine cover and transitions $s_j/s_i$. These three things (embedding, cover, transitions) are all compatibly mapped to each other.